# Socket.io server can't broadcast to room

Tags: node.js, socket.io, broadcast

```
io.on("connection", function(socket){ 
    ...
    socket.on("join", function(id){
        socket.join(room);
        socket.broadcast.to(room).emit("joined", ...);
        ...
    });
    ...
});
```

`socket.broadcast.to(room).emit("joined", ...);` haven't any effect
it doesn't emit to the room the event

i've already tried to use:
`socket.to(room).emit("joined", ...)`
`socket.in(room).emit("joined", ...)`
`io.sockets.in(room).emit("joined", ...);`
`io.to(room).emit("joined", ...);`
`io.in(room).emit("joined", ...);`

i'm using socket.io server v1.3.7

any solution?

Comment: It would be helpful to see more code.  I don't think you'll get much of a response with just this.

Comment: @xkcd149 thanks for tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've searched on github and nobody knows the origin of this problem..
Probably is a systematic problem of socket.io.

Answer (score 2):

Try

`io.to(room).emit("joined", ...);`

Comment: @spikerola is `room` defined and try to do `socket.join(room);` if `room` is defined.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get what you're after by emitting to all the sockets in the room. If you need to exclude the socket currently joining, emitting the event prior to joining should give you the desired behavior.

```
socket.join('roomName');
io.sockets.in('roomName').emit('joined', ...);
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify: I already tried to use this method. Now I'll update

Comment: Huh. That's strange... I'm very interested in why this isn't working, but I don't think I can help you more here. I'll lurk in the background and hope someone else knows what's going on here. Hope your problem gets sorted out soon!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
io.sockets['in'](socket.room).emit('joined',....
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like messing with `socket.id` has bad consequences, best to avoid it!